# How to filter array of data that meets given criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

Here, I have nested array object `categories` which contains nested array of objects `product` and `images` inside `product` array object. `product` array contains `images` array and both arrays objects contain `prodctId`. So, `product` array object has `name` property and `images` array object has `url` property. I wanted to filter and map `name` and `url` properties which have the same `prodctId` property.

Here is the whole object structure

```
{
  "data": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "categoryId": "aeb50ed6-580d-a065-383a-e3932fbec6a1",
        "name": "Electronics",
        "products": [
          {
            "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2",
            "name": "Small Soft Salad",
            "price": 841,
            "discount": 23,
            "unitsSold": 5,
            "images": [
              {
                "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/511dBXGmAtL._AC_UL320_.jpg",
                "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2"
              },
              {
                "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/71MIvKxxSvL._AC_UL320_.jpg",
                "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2"
              },
              {
                "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81loLb-NTYL._AC_UL320_.jpg",
                "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2"
              },
              {
                "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/81goU9h-jnL._AC_UL320_.jpg",
                "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2"
              },
              {
                "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/61pUul1oDlL._AC_UL320_.jpg",
                "productId": "f1ea5d7a-c26e-d850-52b5-9ac4c19668f2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "productId": "b2d38cf6-b8c7-6449-e13a-8ef3bdd12dd0",
            "name": "Tasty Plastic Pants",
            "price": 250,
            "discount": 44,
            "unitsSold": 2,
            "images": [
              {
                "url": "https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/511dBXGmAtL._AC_UL320_.jpg",
                "productId": "b2d38cf6-b8c7-6449-e13a-8ef3bdd12dd0"
              },
```

Here is my react component

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import useStore from "./store/store";

const FILMS_QUERYy = gql`
  {
    categories {
      categoryId
      name
      products {
        productId
        name
        price
        discount
        unitsSold
        images {
          productId
          url
        }
      }
      subCategories {
        name
        subCategoryId
        categoryId
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Hero = () => {
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);
  const furniture = useStore((state) => state.furnitures);
  const electronic = useStore((state) => state.electronics);
  const accessorie = useStore((state) => state.accessories);
  const vehicle = useStore((state) => state.vehicles);
  const fashion = useStore((state) => state.fashions);
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(FILMS_QUERYy);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex space-x-10 justify-center items-center">
        <div onClick={furniture}>Furnitires</div>
        <div onClick={electronic}>Electroinics</div>
        <div onClick={accessorie}>Vehicles</div>
        <div onClick={vehicle}>Accessories</div>
        <div onClick={fashion}>Fashion</div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex space-x-16 p-4 mt-10">
        <div className=" w-64  bg-green-500">
          {data?.categories[filter]?.subCategories?.map((launch) => (
            <div key={launch.name}>{launch.name}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 p-10 font text-2xl  bg-green-500 ">
          {" "}
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2">
            {data?.categories[filter]?.products?.map((product) => (
              <div className="" key={product.name}>
                <div className="  bg-white rounded">
                  {/* <img
                    className=""
                    src="https://shoplly-api.techawks.io/storage/511dBXGmAtL._AC_UL320_.jpg"
                  /> */}
                  <div>{product?.name}</div>
                  <div>{product?.price}</div>
                  <div>
                    <div>
                      {product.images
                        .map((img) => (
                          <div key={img.url}></div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

In this case, all images are mapped to each product `name` which is inappropriate. I need each product `name` to be mapped to it's own image `url` based on `productId`.

How can I achieve this using `filter` method or any other method if available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Check the condition for same id's while map

```
{product.images.map((img) =>
            img.productId === product.productId ? (
              <div key={img.url}></div>
            ) : null
)}
```

Comment: it shows all images inside a single product name

Comment: yes because the ID matches all the id's inside the images array of objects as per your ask ....

Comment: do you need a single one out of it ?

Comment: I need a single `image` mapped to it's own `name`

Comment: not so clear, mapped to its own name in the sense ?? how, each id matches all id's under images .. so what exactly you need ?